# DOMContentLoaded very slow in Chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net, performance, domcontentloaded

I have a complex ASP.NET page, portal type, containing multiple sub-modules.
Some are classic ASP.NET user controls (with server side logic), while other are pure client-side (kendoui / jquery / ko / webapi).

The problem is the page loads very slow in Chrome.
Checking its timeline in Chrome Dev Tools I see DOMContentReady is fired after almost 1 min, while first paint starts after about 11 s.

The same page loads in FF in about 20-25 s, which is normal (giving page complexity).

[image: Timeline in Chrome]

Any idea what is causing this and how can it be fixed?

Thank you

Comment: We have no idea what resources your page uses. There are numerous online tools that will help you narrow down issues. Might consider profiling your server code also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was causing the problem.
The page was using Telerik Ajax TreeView control, which had a very complex node structure.
The tree was rendered very fast in FF, but very slow in Chrome.
As soon as I removed it, Chrome rendered the page fast as well.
So I'm going to redesign the page with a different control, which offer consistent performance across different browsers